# SharePoint Deployment using WSP

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I am looking for best practices for deploying frequent custom code changes to SharePoint 2010 server, my changes include all kind of changes like web parts, content types, workflows, feature receivers, pages images and scripts in layouts folder etc. So far what I have found in documentation is that WSP packages are recommended for deployments for SharePoint. I have few questions regarding frequent code changes using WSP packages

1. Do we need to retract a WSP package before installing updated WSP package? What happens to previous code deployment through this package. Do we need to keep all previous changes in wsp package, so that when we retract and remove old version we get all code changes from previous version and new version.
2. Keeping all the code changes in wsp package through various deployments can cause issues in case we have content type and list instances included in the package, how to manage this kind of changes?
3. If we make new wsp packages for each iteration of changes, wont it clog my server with a a lot of wsp packages, one for each code change cycle?

Comment: Judging by the number of times 'Sharepoint' appears in your question 'd suggest [sharepoint.se] would be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill try to answer your questions:

1. yes and no. if you are deploying assembly code changes then you can retract the solution without deactivating any features. This will update the assemblies in the GAC. If you need to update resources in the features like content types etc, you will need to deactivate / activate feature.
2. What I have started to do to mitigate this problem is all my wsp provision all my content trough code, no xml for content types, list instances, etc. Then what I do Is I keep track of the current version of my feature (using web.Properties bag or something). Anytime I activate the feature I check the current version and run the appropriate code for that version. So in feature activated I have something like:

   ```
   var version = //get version here from property bag or list etc

   if (version < 1.2){ 
       provisioFinanceContentType();
       createFinanceList();
   }

   else if (version <1.3)
   {
         //etc.
   }
   version = 1.3
   //persist version to storage
   ```
3. Do not create new WSPs use the revision system described above

Comment: when indenting, you just have to keep on trucking over more.

Comment: weird I never had such issues...maybe I need coffee :)

Comment: I've never experienced a feature I can update without doing the Uninstall-SPSolution, Remove-SPSolution, Add-SPSolution, Install-SPSolution combo.  What has your experience been creating packages don't require that entire chain of pain?

Comment: if you are only updating code you can always only install the assembly in the GAC. If you are provisioning content in the feature then yes, you dont have any way around that

Comment: Oh, I understand. You're not using the standard SharePoint tools, but just overwriting the GAC DLL?

Comment: I use the standard tooling, but when I do code changes I only deploy the assembly. This is a bonus if you do provisioning through code as you can then re-activate your feature and provision eveyrhting as per step 2 above without have to go through the install unninstall solution combo

Comment: @Luis thanks 4 your answer, it clarifies many of my confusions. I still have some related questions in my mind regarding particular scenario I am facing. I have recently landed into a job where I have got a full blown SharePoint setup with live websites containing many customizations. When I came here, team who created this farm had left, and I don’t have any proper documentation available either. By going through the farm setup here I found there is one big fat WSP which contains all the customizations done to the farm, including content types, features, list instances, webparts, pages etc.

Comment: @Luis my question is regarding the deployment package being used which has few item left out as "items in the solution" and many other items like content type binding and features are still part of the deployment package. Now what I wonder is if I should keep updating and deploying this big fat WSP with so many code artifacts included for all my major and minor changes? Or if I exclude items from this package will it also remove items form my farm when I deploy this updated package?

Comment: I would keep deploying your fat wsp otherwise you may have potential issues, depending if that solution does any clean up on deactivate. By default content created by the feature its not deleted on deactivation. Another thing is if you need to rebuild your dev environment having the original content in the feature will definitely help. Another option is to create a second solution and add your changes to that one. My OCD wouldn't allow that though :)

Comment: I my answer helped you in any way please upvote me / accept my answer. Thanks :)